# How do I program text into textfield?

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, textfield

I am using Xcode 6.3 with Objective-C language. The app that I am building has `UITextField` and `UITextView`. I am wanting to have text show up in the fields/views so that the user will have instructions on what to put into the fields/views. Example, "enter your name". How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the code that you're currently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `UITextField:`

For your `UITextField` you should define the placeholder for the instructions text.

```
_textField.placeholder= @"Your Name";
```

### `UITextView :`

`UITextView` does not have a default placeholder like UITextField.
But you can make the effect like placeholder by following these steps.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _textView.text = @"Enter Comment...";
    _textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _textView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Enter Comment..."]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"Enter Comment...";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the `placeholder` property.

```
let t = UITextField()
t.placeholder = "enter your name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Place holders for text fields is the way you can have some text shown...

```
textField.placeholder  = "Enter your name"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wann change the text just call:

`textfield.text = @"enter your name"`

if you just want to set a placeholder which will disappear on user input use this property :

`textfield.placeholder = @"enter your name"`

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list instructions , please add /place a UIView in appropriate location and show and hide inside your textFieldDidBeginEditing: delegate method.

Note :- place holders might not be appropriate as it has limit to text and your instructions may be huge.